# R S3 generic methods set to visible FALSE

Tags: r, dbplyr, r-s3, rdebug

I have an R object `lf` which is an element of the class `tbl_lazy`:

```
library(dbplyr)
lf <- lazy_frame(a = TRUE, b = 1, c = 2, d = "z", con = simulate_hana())
>class(lf)
[1] "tbl_HDB"  "tbl_lazy" "tbl"
```

With the help of the sloop package, I can see that the generic function `print.tbl_lazy` is set to `visible = FALSE`. This seems to be the reason why printing `print.tbl_lazy` returns `Error: object 'print.tbl_lazy' not found`.

```
   generic       class    visible source
   <chr>         <chr>    <lgl>   <chr>
11 print         tbl_lazy FALSE   registered S3method
```

When I debug `print` I see the call to `print.lazy` and can now see the content of `print.tbl_lazy`.

```
debugging in: function (x, ...)
UseMethod("print")(x)
debug: UseMethod("print")
Browse[2]> n
debugging in: print.tbl_lazy(x)
debug: {
    show_query(x)
}
```

My question is why are all the methods of the class `tbl_lazy` set to `visible = FALSE` and what are the consequences of this? It would appear to me, while it may have some advantages, whatever they might be, it makes the code of the method more difficult to access, which in a language like R, used by so many non technical users, seems to be a big disadvantage.
I wasn't able to find any documentation on this.